# CiviCRM Relationship error

Tags: relationships

I am getting an error on my development site and i have tried everything to fix it but had no Luck.

```
***ERROR***
message:            unknown relationship create error Argument <em class="placeholder">civicrm_relationship</em> is missing.
code:                
exception:          CRM_Core_Exception Object
(
    [errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [error_code] => 0
        )

    [cause:protected] => 
    [_trace:PEAR_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => unknown relationship create error Argument <em class="placeholder">civicrm_relationship</em> is missing.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php
    [line:protected] => 139
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Relationship.php
                    [line] => 565
                    [function] => createMultiple
                    [class] => CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [hidden_custom] => 1
                                    [hidden_custom_group_count] => Array
                                        (
                                            [] => 1
                                        )

                                    [qfKey] => bf18a1feddecedf9bb2d0998921e2ecb_7909
                                    [entryURL] => https://site.co.uk/civicrm/contact/view/rel?cid=140&amp;action=add&amp;reset=1
                                    [relationship_type_id] => 27
                                    [related_contact_id] => 137
                                    [is_current_employer] => 1
                                    [start_date] => 
                                    [end_date] => 
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [is_permission_a_b] => 0
                                   ...
```

I have deleted the relationships re-added them but have had no Luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was i had rules setup with the wrong values hence why it wasn't working. After disabling the rules i am now able to add relationships.

I don't know how it worked but it has.